# Problem booting Ubuntu 16.04 with pre-installed Windows 8.1 on multi-hdd system

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, windows

I have pre-installed Windows 8.1 on a Haier-Y11B (core m machine) . My laptop has 32GB SSD and 500GB hard drive. SSD can be detached with tablet part of the laptop.  Windows is installed on SSD and there isn't enough space left for Ubuntu installation. After installing Ubuntu on hard drive, instead of opening the Grub menu, it opens a GRUB terminal.
Here is what I've tried so far with no success

1. Boot repair inside live ubuntu
2. Turning off secure-boot and fast start
3. Successfully running the following command in windows

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```

Apparently Windows Boot Manager can not mount from the hard drive and only looks into SSD because when I enter `df` command in live Ubuntu, it only shows the partitions of SSD.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score -1):

It may be caused by the the absence of EFI System Partition configuration during the ubuntu installation.

When installing ubuntu you have to setup your partitions and indicate the place of the EFI System Partition or create it if there is none. In your case it should have been created by windows and it should be on the SSD.

Comment: Yes, i did the same, but no luck